# glossaries-extra package problems with sorting сyrillic abbreviations in LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, acronyms, cyrillic, glossaries-extra

I have two issues:

1. Sort the abbreviations so that the first ones are Cyrillic, and then the English terms?
2. Change the style of the list of abbreviations as shown in the picture? How to do it through custom abbreviation style?

Thanks in advance.

MWE:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
% !TeX encoding = utf-8
% !TeX spellcheck = ru_RU
%============================================================================================
% JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF8"
% bib2gls.exe %
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{abbreviations.bib}
% Encoding: UTF-8
@abbreviation{БД,
    short = {БД},
    long = {База Данных}
    }
@abbreviation{ЯМАО,
    short = {ЯМАО},
    long = {Ямало-Ненецкий Автономный Округ}
    }
@abbreviation{ЛПР,
    short = {ЛПР},
    long = {Лицо, Принимающее Решения Лицо, Принимающее Решения Лицо, Принимающее Решения Лицо, Принимающее Решения}
    }
@abbreviation{XML,
    short = {XML},
    long = {eXtensible Markup Language}
    }
@abbreviation{P2P,
    short = {P2P},
    long = {Peer-to-Peer}
    }
@abbreviation{HTTP,
    short = {HTTP},
    long = {Hypertext Transfer Protocol},
    category={common}
    }
\end{filecontents}
%============================================================================================
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=modern]{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX},Renderer=Basic}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
%==========================================================
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\microtypecontext{kerning=russian}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
%==========================================================
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[record,
abbreviations,
postdot,
nonumberlist,
nogroupskip
]{glossaries-extra}
%==========================================================
\renewcommand{\glsabbrvdefaultfont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\setabbreviationstyle{long-short}
%==========================================================
%\newglossarystyle{mylist}{%
%   \setglossarystyle{list}% base this style on the list style
%   \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
%       \item[\glsentryitem{##1}%
%       \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}]--~
%       \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space}%
%}
%\setglossarystyle{mylist}
%==========================================================
\GlsXtrLoadResources[
src={abbreviations}
]
\begin{document}
\setlist[description]{leftmargin=!, nosep, itemindent=!, labelsep=.33333em, before={\renewcommand\makelabel[1]{########1 --}}} % Change for glossaries

\printunsrtglossary[type=abbreviations]

\setlist[description]{style=standard} % reset settings back to default

\vspace{20pt}

First use:
    
\gls{XML}; \gls{ЯМАО}; \gls{ЛПР}; \gls{БД}; \gls{P2P}; \gls{HTTP}.
    
Next use:
    
\gls{XML}; \gls{ЯМАО}; \gls{ЛПР}; \gls{БД}; \gls{P2P}; \gls{HTTP}.
\end{document}
```

My result now:

[image]

What I want to get:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should make two glossaries? One with English and one with Russian abbreviations? You can then print them consecutively. Also (unrelated), it's `ЯНАО`, not `ЯМАО`.

Comment: @Michael Fraiman This is mistake.